# React native: Which function is fired when There is a focus on TextInput and it reached its limit still a input button is pressed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput

I am new to react-native. I have 3 TextInput Field `t1, t2, t3`. I have done focusing on next input field when reached its limit. Now I am stuck with a situation that somehow there is a focus on my textinput field `t1` and `t1` has already reached its max limit. But when I am pressing another input it's not focusing to the next input field `t2`.

```
<TextInput
onChangeText={text => this.setState({ v1: text })}
keyboardType='number-pad'
maxLength={1}
autoCompleteType={'off'}
autoFocus={true}
ref={ref => this.v1Ref = ref}
onChange={event => {
if (event.nativeEvent.text !== '') {
  this.v2Ref.focus();
}
}}
/>

<TextInput
onChangeText={text => this.setState({ v2: text })}
keyboardType='number-pad'
maxLength={1}
autoCompleteType={'off'}
ref={ref => this.v2Ref = ref}
onChange={event => {
if (event.nativeEvent.text !== '') {
  this.v3Ref.focus();
}
}}
onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace') {
  if(this.state.v2== '')
    this.v1Ref.focus(); //here it is focusing on field t1 on backspace press and then if I am trying to give another input It's not going to t2 because t1 has reached its limit.
  }
}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on my computer

If you are using Android Emulator
This function will not work because it is written in [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onkeypress)

> Note: on Android only the inputs from soft keyboard are handled, not the hardware keyboard inputs.

If you are using an emulator you need to press the buttons inside the phone with the mouse and not the computer keyboard

Try inserting console.log
Inside the function to see if it works

```
onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
console.log('onKeyPress')
if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace') {
  if(this.state.v2== '')
    this.v1Ref.focus(); 
  }
}}
```